# phonegap posting data doesn't work on android device

Tags: php, jquery, cordova

I've been working on this app for the past two days and I can't seem to resolve this issue. I used [Sam Croft's Example](http://samcroft.co.uk/2012/posting-data-from-a-phonegap-app-to-a-server-using-jquery/) to create the form and post data into mysql. It works perfectly fine from the browser, but doesn't in a mobile device.

Here is my form

```
<form id="registerForm">
    <div id="register-thankyou" style="display: none;">
        Thank you.                
    </div>
    <div id="register-form">
        <p class="mandatory" style="color:#A00;font-weight:700;">* indicates Required</p>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="text-field">
            <label for="fullname">Full Name*:</label>
            <input type="text" name="fullname" value="" placeholder="" class="required" id="fullname" />
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="text-field">
            <label for="email">Email Address*:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="" class="required" id="email"  />
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <input type="submit" value="Register !!!" /> 
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

My JavaScript `register.js`

```
$('#registerForm').submit(function() {
    var url = 'http://my-domain.com/register.php';
    var postData = $(this).serialize();

    var $fname = $('#fullname').val();
    var $email = $('#email').val();

    if ($fname == "" && $email == "") {
            alert('Please fill in all the fields.');  
    } else {
        //submit the form
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            crossDomain: true,
            cache: false,
            async:true,
            data: postData,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                alert(data);
                $('#register-thankyou').show();
                $('#register-form').hide();
            },
            error: function(){
                console.log(data);
                alert('There was an error while registering. Please, Try again later!');
            }
        }); //$.ajax
    }
    return false;

});
```

My `register.php`

```
include 'config.php';
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

$con = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);

$full_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["fullname"]);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);

$sql = "INSERT INTO register (fullName,email) ";
$sql .= "VALUES ('$full_name', '$email')";

if (!mysql_query($sql, $con)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
} else {
    echo "Registered record added";
}

mysql_close($con);
```

**Everything I have tried:**

1. Whitelisted all the domains I'm working with including `localhost`, according to [PhoneGap Domain Whitelist Guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html)
2. Added support for All origins `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *')`
3. Set `crossDomain: true` in the Ajax call

After implementing all the above, I can't seem to post data into mysql via Android Mobile devices. Works fine from the browser.

Comment: In your ajax method, try assigning `dataType` to `json`. `dataType: "json"`

Comment: @DawsonLoudon I added that, still the same issue. Is it possible to insert data into mysql using `GET` instead of `POST`?

Comment: Yes, you can use GET and POST interchangeably. The only issue is that GET accepts less data than POST, but you should be fine in the case above. One more thing to check (just asking because I didn't see it above), do you have `<access origin="*" />` in your `config.xml`?

Comment: Okay thanks. Yes I have `<access origin="*" />` in my `config.xml`. Let me try using `GET` if it works will post my approach for others.

Answer (score 0):

try change your javascript into this without serialize method

```
$('#submitButton').click(function() {
    var url = 'http://my-domain.com/register.php';
    formData = {
        fullname: $('#fullname').val(),
        email: $('#email').val()
    }
    if ($('#fullname').val() == "" && $('#email').val() == "") {
        alert('Please fill in all the fields.');
    } else {
        //submit the form
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            crossDomain: true,
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            data: formData,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                alert(data);
                $('#register-thankyou').show();
                $('#register-form').hide();
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log(data);
                alert('There was an error while registering. Please, Try again later!');
            }
        }); //$.ajax
    }
});
```

then add submitButton id

html

```
<input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Register !!!" />
```